# Yii independent linkButton not working within form tags

Tags: php, yii, hyperlink

I am using Yii and I have a form wrapped in tabs. In one of these tabs I need to put a link (call a `controller/action` with parameters) independent from the form content.
I've tried to use `CHtml::linkButton` but it doesn't work.

The code scheme of the form is the following:

```
<?php $form=$this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
    'id'=>'project-form',
    'enableAjaxValidation'=>true,
)); ?>

//...input elements

<?php echo CHtml::linkButton('Download',
    array(
        'submit'=>$this->createUrl('controller/action'),
        'params'=>array(
                'results'=>CJSON::encode(array('foo'=>'bar'))
        ))
); ?>

//...other input elements

<?php $this->endWidget(); ?>
```

When I click on the link nothing happens. If I put the `linkButton` code outside the form it works properly.

Is there a workaround for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to use a button to let the user download some sort of file. For this situation AJAX won't work as it's not capable of saving files to a users computer.

What you want to do is to create just the anchor tag.  The function linkButton is designed for is to be a button that will submit the current form. If you're using bootstrap the below will also make it look like a button.

```
CHtml::link('Download', array('controller/action', 'myparam' => 'paramvalue'), array('class', 'btn btn-primary'));
```

Make sure you set the correct headers for downloading the file.

Comment: I would need to submit a POST request but, as far as I've seen, this allows me just to perform a GET request.

Answer (score 0):

In this case you should use [ajaxLink](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CHtml#ajaxLink-detail)

Example:

```
echo CHtml::ajaxLink(
$text = 'Click me', 
$url = '/', 
$ajaxOptions=array (
    'type'=>'POST',
    'dataType'=>'json',
    'success'=>'function(html){ jQuery("#your_id").html(html); }'
    ), 
$htmlOptions=array ()
);
```

Comment: The controller/action in my case is supposed to generate and directly download a file through HTML2PDF extension. Unfortunately the ajax approach doesn't seem to work.